# on click append and replace portion of div to another div

Tags: jquery

I have a fiddle set up , i'm just learning and getting a bit confused on how to make this work.

https://jsfiddle.net/twxxwj1m/6/

When i click on any text "select" it opens a hidden container with names that i want to be able to add to the container i just clicked "select" from. So if i click on the "select" text in the box container labled QB - Select Quarterback , and a new box opens that lists a few players to add , i want to click "add" on any of those boxes , I want to remove that div from the available list and add it to the starting list in place of where i originally made the select from. I'm confused and probably even more confusing trying to describe this.

```
$("#available-players .quarterbacks").hide();
$("#available-players .runningbacks").hide();
$("#available-players .widereceivers").hide();
$("#available-players .tightends").hide();
$("#available-players .flex").hide();
$("#available-players .defense").hide();
$("#available-players h1").hide();

$(".quarterbacks .show-players").click(function(){
    $("#starting-players").hide();
    $("#available-players .quarterbacks,#available-players h1").show();
});
$(".runningbacks .show-players").click(function(){
    $("#starting-players").hide();
    $("#available-players .runningbacks,#available-players h1").show();
});
$(".widereceivers .show-players").click(function(){
    $("#starting-players").hide();
    $("#available-players .widereceivers,#available-players h1").show();
});
$(".tightends .show-players").click(function(){
    $("#starting-players").hide();
    $("#available-players .tightends,#available-players h1").show();
});
$(".flex .show-players").click(function(){
    $("#starting-players").hide();
    $("#available-players .flex,#available-players h1").show();
});
$(".defense .show-players").click(function(){
    $("#starting-players").hide();
    $("#available-players .defense,#available-players h1").show();
});


$(".quarterbacks .add-players").click(function(){
    $("#available-players .quarterbacks,#available-players h1").hide();
    $("#starting-players").show();
});
$(".runningbacks .add-players").click(function(){
    $("#available-players .runningbacks,#available-players h1").hide();
    $("#starting-players").show();
});
$(".widereceivers .add-players").click(function(){
    $("#available-players .widereceivers,#available-players h1").hide();
    $("#starting-players").show();
});
$(".tightends .add-players").click(function(){
    $("#available-players .tightends,#available-players h1").hide();
    $("#starting-players").show();
});
$(".flex .add-players").click(function(){
    $("#available-players .flex,#available-players h1").hide();
    $("#starting-players").show();
});
$(".defense .add-players").click(function(){
    $("#available-players .defense,#available-players h1").hide();
    $("#starting-players").show();
});
```

Is what i have so far the easiest and best method to do this ?

Comment: Are you looking to do the same thing in the jsfiddle with a better code ? Or are you looking for something different ?

Comment: I'd like whatever would be best way to make this work. I'm just dipping my toes in JavaScript and want to learn the best method